# Manage Increase MAX BYTES or Decrease USED BYTES ORACLE TABLESPACE

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I have one problem while creating external table which has 3.2 million records

The external file has 3.2 million records as a `.CSV` file format and I have created the EXTERNAL file in Oracle,

```
CREATE TABLE SCOT.RXD32LExt
(
    SORT_CODE       NUMBER(9),
    ACCOUNT_NUM     NUMBER(11),
    BANK_NAME       VARCHAR2(6),
    TRAN_DEBIT      NUMBER(9),
    TRAN_CREDIT     NUMBER(9),
    SEQ_NUM         NUMBER(11),
    RXD_FLAG        NUMBER(4),
    REPORT_FLAG     NUMBER(4),
    FLAG            VARCHAR2(4) 
) 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( 
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER 
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY GK3_F
  ACCESS PARAMETERS 
  ( 
    records delimited by newline
    fields terminated by ',' 
    optionally enclosed by '"'
    missing field values are null
    (
      SORT_CODE, ACCOUNT_NUM, BANK_NAME, TRAN_DEBIT, TRAN_CREDIT, 
      SEQ_NUM, RXD_FLAG, REPORT_FLAG, FLAG 
    ) 
  ) 
  LOCATION ('32LRecords.csv') 
) 
PARALLEL 
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED; 

Table Created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM SCOT.RXD32LExt;
```

My database is facing memory issue out of bound exception. since SYSTEM user is not having sufficient space in database and I have check the below query for tablespace

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, 
    SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 "USED MEGABYTES",
    SUM(maxbytes)/1024/1024 "MAX MEGABYTES" 
FROM dba_data_files 
WHERE tablespace_name IN ('SYSTEM', 'USERS') 
GROUP BY tablespace_name;

Output
------

TABLESPACE_NAME - USED MEGABYTES - MAX MEGABYTES
----------------------------------------------
USERS              100              11264
SYSTEM             600              600
```

If I need to `DECREASE USED MEGABYTE`S means what i need to do or
If I need to `INCREASE MAX MEGABYTES` MEANS what I need to do.

I did the following query

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 
'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF' RESIZE 10G;
```

but the above alter query has increase the used megabytes memory of not max memory.

```
TABLESPACE_NAME - USED MEGABYTES - MAX MEGABYTES
----------------------------------------------
USERS              100              11264
SYSTEM             3200             600
```

Comment: external table's(SCOT.RXD32LExt) value need to store in to real oracle table(SCOT.RXD32L) and compare with another one internal table(UID_DOC) for finding the common records between SCOT.RXD32L and SCOT.UID_DOC and the error I have received. "ORA-29913: error is executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01653: unable to exten table SCOT.RXD32L by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM"

Comment: Hi from the same above method I load upto 1Lakhs records, it not related to .xls or .xlsx file. the error is related to table space in SYSTEM user. the process is fine and the query will import to minimum records, this giving the issue when data load is exceeding the maximum records.